# How to pass parameters to a the Add Method of a DataRow?

Tags: c#, datarow

One of the method signatures for the DataRow Add Method is:

```
DataRow.Add(params object[] values)
```

When using the above, if I am passing in some strings for example, do I have to do it like the following:

```
DataRow.Add(new object[]{"a","b","c"});
```

or can I just do it like the following:

```
DataRow.Add("a","b","c");
```

Would both ways work?

The same question applies to the a collection of DataColumns when passing adding columns to a DataTable using the AddRange method.  Do I have to use DataTable.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]{}) or can I just pass the columns without instantiating a new array (meaning does it do it indirectly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the both will work fine. Though the second syntax is preferable.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, both ways would work.  The `params` keyword is magic like that.

Comment: Yes this is what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, both ways should work, since the signature declares the array as a 'params' argument.
If the method wouldn't be able to handle it in this way, they shouldn't have declared the array argument as 'params'.